# VS2017 Azure Functions v2 - Test Project not picking up changes from referenced project, without manually building

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, xunit, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to write some tests for azure functions v2 and am running into some difficulties in that VS2017 does not seem to pick up changes in my azure function project, in my test project, without me rebuilding the project manually.

https://github.com/swissarmykirpan/AzureFunctionIssue

Maybe it's just my machine??

Try adding an additional method onto the `Hello` class and see if the unit test class can pick up the new method.

Also, if you go to definition on the `Hello` class from the test project, it does not go to the source file, but decompiled metadata instead.

HELP!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tested your code on my side and found that I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned. Also I tried to remove the post-build event cmd you wrote about xcopy, but without luck.

> Also, if you go to definition on the Hello class from the test project, it does not go to the source file, but decompiled metadata instead.

Per my understanding, you could define classes out of your Azure Function project for a workaround to meet your requirement. Since you are using Azure Functions V2 (.NET Core), you could define your classes under a Class Library (.NET Standard) or Class Library (.NET Core), then your Azure Function V2 references it and your xUnit Test Project could reference it and test the methods.